# React Router how to know the path

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I know this info I could find it online, and Did try. The problem is that I don't know if its for the many different versions, but every page I check it provides (somme times completely) different solutions.

Given this code:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
/* ...More code here... */
class Footer extends React.Component {
    render () {
        const current_page = location.href.replace('http://localhost:3000', '');
        return (
                <footer>
                <a href="/" className={current_page == '/' ? 'active' : ''}>Game</a>
                <a href="/page" className={current_page == '/page' ? 'active' : ''}>Page</a>
                <p>Current route <strong>{current_page}</strong></p>
            </footer>
        );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <div>
            <h1>RactJS app</h1>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={ Game } />
                <Route exact path="/page" component={ Page } />
            </Switch>
            <Footer></Footer>
        </div>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I could I get `current_page` *in the React way*? right now I had to use this so it compiles: `/* eslint-disable no-restricted-globals */`

As you can guess, I'm pretty new in ReactJS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to get the `location pathname` in the `Footer` component which doesn't receive the router props, you can wrap the `Footer` component with `withRouter` and then access the path like `this.props.location.pathname`

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
class Footer extends React.Component {
    render () {
        const current_page = this.props.location.pathname;
        return (
                <footer>
                <a href="/" className={current_page == '/' ? 'active' : ''}>Game</a>
                <a href="/page" className={current_page == '/page' ? 'active' : ''}>Page</a>
                <p>Current route <strong>{current_page}</strong></p>
            </footer>
        );
    }
}

const WrappedFooter = withRouter(Footer)
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <div>
            <h1>RactJS app</h1>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={ Game } />
                <Route exact path="/page" component={ Page } />
            </Switch>
            <WrappedFooter></WrappedFooter>
        </div>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: This makes more sense to me! but i get  `Failed to compile: 'withRouter' is not defined  no-undef` how can I fix this?

Comment: Seems to be fixed adding withRouter in  `import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';` thanks!

Comment: Yes you neede to import it. And I did add it in my answer. Glad it solved your issue

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are using react-router v4.

You can get current path from `this.props.location.pathname`.

So

```
const current_page = this.props.location.pathname;
...
```

And instead of using anchor with className on activePath, you can use `NavLink` from react-router.

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
...

<NavLink exact to="/" activeClassName="active">Game</NavLink>
<NavLink exact to="/page" activeClassName="active">Page</NavLink>
```

And wrap your Footer with `withRouter`. On your footer.js, use follows.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
...

export default withRouter(Footer);
```

Comment: Thanks for you input. I already tried that, but inside the `Footer` component throws this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined`

Comment: Instead of comparing path manually, I suggest to use `NavLin` and use `withRouter` hoc.

Comment: Thanks for the navLink, didn't know about this! +1 ^^

Answer (score 0):

```html
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
class Footer extends React.Component {
    render () {
        const current_page = this.props.location.pathname;
        return (
                <footer>
                <a href="/" className={current_page == '/' ? 'active' : ''}>Game</a>
                <a href="/page" className={current_page == '/page' ? 'active' : ''}>Page</a>
                <p>Current route <strong>{current_page}</strong></p>
            </footer>
        );
    }
}

const WrappedFooter = withRouter(Footer)
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <div>
            <h1>RactJS app</h1>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={ Game } />
                <Route exact path="/page" component={ Page } />
            </Switch>
            <WrappedFooter></WrappedFooter>
        </div>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```